# Call OSGi service from sightly javascript use function

Tags: aem, rhino, sightly

I am trying to access an OSGi service from a [sightly javascript use function](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/use-api-in-javascript.html).  Through the sling [SlingScriptHelper](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling6/org/apache/sling/api/scripting/SlingScriptHelper.html#getService(java.lang.Class)).  I can call the `sling.getService(Service.class)` method from javascript, but I do not know how to specify the class in javascript.

It looks like it [should be possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Scripting_Java) to reference java classes using the fully qualified name or using rhino's `importPackage(..)`.

However, I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.sling.scripting.sightly.SightlyException:
org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Can't find method
org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.InternalScriptHelper.getService(object).
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do this, prepend `Packages` to the fully-qualified class name, e.g.

```
var myService = sling.getService(Packages.com.myco.MyService);
```

(where `com.myco.MyService` is the service interface)

See https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-commons/blob/master/content/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/acs-commons/sightly/templates/dhlm.js#L23 for an example.